# Null pointer exception

Tags: java, android

i wonder if anyone can help me.
ive an activity with 9 buttons which when clicked change the colour of another button, each of the 9 buttons change the colour of the button to a different colour using:

```
currentcolour.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0));
```

for custom colours, or:

```
currentcolour.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

for default colours

when i run the application on a tablet and the button is clicked, it throws a null pointer exception:

```
07-09 10:26:21.492: D/AndroidRuntime(8157): Shutting down VM
07-09 10:26:21.492: W/dalvikvm(8157): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception   (group=0x41986930)
07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157):     at sjtech.rompa.wifi.Wifi$1.onClick(Wifi.java:54)
07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4452)
07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157):     at android.widget.Button.performClick  (Button.java:148)
07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run  (View.java:18428)
07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 10:26:21.539: D/dalvikvm(8157): GC_CONCURRENT freed 668K, 31% free 8844K/12804K, paused    1ms+4ms, total 33ms
```

here is the .java

```
package sjtech.rompa.wifi;

import com.javacodegeeks.android.bluetoothtest.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


   //called when the activity is first created
public class Wifi extends Activity {


private Button currentcolour;
private Button redbtn; 
private Button grnbtn;
private Button bluebtn; 
private Button yellowbtn;
private Button orangebtn; 
private Button purplebtn;
private Button pinkbtn; 
private Button whitebtn;
private Button resetbtn;
private Button blueleftarrow; 

//Button wifi_screen changes between screens.
@Override   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wifi);




            //****RED BUTTON****
           // Get a reference to the button
    redbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redbtn);  
         // Set the click listener to run the code.
    redbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                 // red button's click event
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "RED " ,   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
          currentcolour.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);


            }   
        });



            //****GREEN BUTTON****
           // Get a reference to the button
                grnbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.grnbtn);
         // Set the click listener to run the code.
                grnbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
           // green button's click event
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "GREEN " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    currentcolour.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0));

                }
            });


                //****BLUE BUTTON****
               // Get a reference to the button
            bluebtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bluebtn);
             // Set the click listener to run the code.
            bluebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  // blue button's click event
                          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "BLUE " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            currentcolour.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
        });


            //****YELLOW BUTTON****
           // Get a reference to the button
        yellowbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yellowbtn);
         // Set the click listener to run the code.
        yellowbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             // yellow button's click event
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "YELLOW" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        currentcolour.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }
        });



    //****ORANGE BUTTON****
        // Get a reference to the button
    orangebtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.orangebtn);

       // Set the click listener to run the code.
    orangebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
     // orange button's click event
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ORANGE" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    currentcolour.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 100, 0));

        }
    });


    //****PURPLE BUTTON****
     // Get a reference to the button
    purplebtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.purplebtn);

     // Set the click listener to run the code.
    purplebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

     // purple button's click event
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "PURPLE" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
           currentcolour.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(128, 0, 128));
}
});



                                         //****PINK BUTTON****
        // Get a reference to the button
     pinkbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pinkbtn);

     // Set the click listener to run the code.
              pinkbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                          @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

            // pink button's click event
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "PINK" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
       currentcolour.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 20, 147));
                                    }
});



                                      //****WHITE BUTTON****
 // Get a reference to the button
    whitebtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.whitebtn);

        //Set the click listener to run the code.
    whitebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

        //white button's click event
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "WHITE" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    currentcolour.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                                        }
                                    });

                                        //****GRAY BUTTON****
// Get a reference to the button
   resetbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.resetbtn);
                                     // Set the click listener to run the code.
    resetbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

 // gray button's click event
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "RESET" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    currentcolour.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                                        }
                                        });


       //****blueleftarrow BUTTON****
      //changes from wifi to bluetooth page.      
     // Get a reference to the button
  blueleftarrow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.blueleftarrow);

// Set the click listener to run the code.
   blueleftarrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

 //blueleftarrow's click event
   Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Bluetoothsetup.class);
   startActivity(intent);   


        }
    });  

}
}
```

and the .xml

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/clouds"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:layoutMode="clipBounds"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:visibility="visible"
tools:context=".Wifi" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="193dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="0dp"
    android:layout_y="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/rompalogo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/orangebtn"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_x="223dp"
    android:layout_y="750dp"
    android:background="@drawable/orangecircle2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/whitebtn"
    style="@android:style/Animation"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_x="63dp"
    android:layout_y="673dp"
    android:background="@drawable/whitecircle2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pinkbtn"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_x="395dp"
    android:layout_y="685dp"
    android:background="@drawable/pinkcircle2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/resetbtn"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_x="223dp"
    android:layout_y="497dp"
    android:background="@drawable/greycircle2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/purplebtn"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_x="432dp"
    android:layout_y="493dp"
    android:background="@drawable/purplecircle2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/yellowbtn"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_x="25dp"
    android:layout_y="499dp"
    android:background="@drawable/yellowcircle2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bluebtn"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_x="387dp"
    android:layout_y="332dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bluecircle2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/redbtn"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_x="223dp"
    android:layout_y="259dp"
    android:background="@drawable/redcircle2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/grnbtn"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_x="62dp"
    android:layout_y="340dp"
    android:background="@drawable/greencircle2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/blueleftarrow"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_x="6dp"
    android:layout_y="53dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blueleftarrow" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/currentcolour"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="438dp"
    android:layout_y="66dp"
    android:text="" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException 07-09 10:26:21.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8157): at sjtech.rompa.wifi.Wifi$1.onClick(Wifi.java:54)` So what is on line 54?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) TL;DR: Debugging help is a bit off topic, and have you looked at the line in the error message, and deugged where the NPE is? 54? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't initialized `Button currentcolour;` and you are using it in click listener as *(i.e)* `currentcolour.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);` which is causing `NullPointerException` because `currentcolour` is `null`.

```
currentcolour= (Button) findViewById(R.id.currentcolour);//Initialize first
```

<sub>[*Want to Know More about `NullPointerException`?*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you've used `currentcolor`, which hasn't been initialized and you're trying to use it. That's why you're getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: If this doesn't completely solve the problem...then check the statements where you've used **Toast**. I'm not sure, as I couldn't understand that bit very clearly according to you're question, there might be problem there

Comment: this is again correct, but ive accepted the first answer, many thanks

Comment: great! have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
//Initialize
currentcolour= (Button) findViewById(R.id.currentcolour);

//Set Colour
currentcolour.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: You can mark as answer if you like for others if they face similar problem in future and don't forget to give up vote for right answers

Answer (score 0):

in your code at line number 54 you are using

```
currentcolour.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

without initializing `currentcolor` `button` object first initialize it the use it.
if you use curentcolor without initailizing it you will get `NullPointerException`